# Tridion 2013 SP1 TCMUploadAssembly - database time out error

Tags: 2013, templating, database

I am trying to upload a .NET assembly to Tridion 2013 SP1 environment and keep getting this database timeout error (please see below). I looked for CM logs and the event viewer but nothing is being logged and manually updating the dll in the CMS does not save either. It appears that the Tridion CM is unable to communicate with the database, however I see all of the publications, schemas, etc., being populated correctly. Thanks in advance for any suggestions for troubleshooting.

A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ITEMS_UPDATEBINARYCONTENT".
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.The wait operation timed out

at[remote] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(...)
   at[remote] System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(...)
   at[remote] System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(...)
   at[remote] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(...)
   at[remote] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(...)
   at[remote] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(...)
   at[remote] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(...)
   at[remote] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(...)
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.SetBinaryContent(...)
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.SetBinaryContent(...)
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.ContentManagement.ItemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.IItemDataMapper.SetBinaryContent(.
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.SetBinaryContent(...)
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Template.OnSaved(...)
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(...)
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(...)
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.SetupDefaultTemplates.SaveBinaryContent(...)
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.SetupDefaultTemplates.SaveBinaryContent(...)
   at[remote] Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.TemplateAssemblyStorage.StoreTemplateAssembly(...)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [the solution provided in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565642/timeout-when-uploading-images). That solution saved me a couple of times and apparently a few [other people](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/116/timeout-in-the-tridionuploadassembly) as well.